# Verbose debug printing in arduino?

Tags: debugging, arduino, preprocessor

I'd like to have some sort of verbose debug printing in arduino that can be enabled/disabled by a flag.  For example I'd like the ability to do something like

```
#define VERBOSE
#define VERBOSE_PRINT(text) #ifdef VERBOSE Serial.println(text); #endif
```

Later in code:

```
VERBOSE_PRINT("Doing something");
```

if VERBOSE is defined then I should get stuff out over the serial port and if it's not defined then that code won't be compiled.  Unfortunately this isn't working.  I get the error: "error: '#' is not followed by a macro parameter".  So I'm wondering what's the best way to get an optionally compiled print (or anything for that matter).  Of course I could manually write out the #ifdefs, but I'd like it streamlined so that it doesn't take up a ton space and so I don't have to write it out each time I'd like to use it.  Is a function w/ the #ifdef inside the function the best way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

```
#define VERBOSE

#ifdef VERBOSE
#define VERBOSE_PRINT(str) Serial.println(str)
#else
#define VERBOSE_PRINT(str)
#endif

VERBOSE_PRINT("Doing something");
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  Seems to work ok for numbers, but not for text.  Not too sure why that makes any sense, but it's the result I'm getting.  For example VERBOSE_PRINT(12345); VERBOSE_PRINT("Test") results in:

12345
ÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿ